# Haskell function list (find even indexes and add them) ~ Code explanation

Tags: haskell

The below code is a  function sum2 which as an
argument takes a list of numbers and returns the sum of elements of even
indexes. Can anyone explain how this code works? What are x and Xs and how does this find the even numbers and add them ?

```
sum2 :: [Integer] -> Integer
sum2 [] = 0
sum2 (x:xs) | mod x 2 == 0 = x + sum2 xs
            | otherwise = sum2 xs

sum2' :: [Integer] -> Integer
sum2' [] = 0
sum2' [x] = x
sum2' (x:_:xs) = x + sum2' xs
```

so if you hit in the console sum2 [2,3,3,4,0,6] it will add only the even numbers and the result will be: 12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum2` looks like it sums all the *values* that are even. `x` is the "current" value (head of the list), and `xs` is the rest. If `mod x 2 == 0` (even), then add `x` to the sum of the rest of the list, otherwise skip it and sum the rest of the list.

`sum2'` chooses elements based on position rather than value.

1. The last case, if there are *at least two* elements in the list, skip the second one and add the first one to the sum of the rest.
2. If there is *exactly one*, that's the sum.
3. If there are *zero*, the sum is 0.

So it is dropping every second element, summing the first, third, fifth, etc. (index 0, 2, 4, etc.).

Comment: i didn't understand your first point, why should we skip the second one and add the first ?

Comment: @csandreas1 It's basically popping off 2 elements of the list at once, and keeping one of them. If you want the even indexed ones you keep the first, and if you want odd indexed you take the second (and the single element case also ignores the element). The `_` basically means ignore this element - since we're not naming it, we can't use it.